# Please support the Area 51 Proposal for Greek! We need ≥ 400 avid users

Tags: discussion, greek, stackexchange

Click [here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/123680/greek-language?referrer=ZjJjMTU4YmIwMGIxZGM1MTNjZjRjNWIzNzIwMTZjOTA3MWQ1MTM4ZjYyNWM3YTM3N2UyNmM0M2JlMDk4ZTUzYwyBb88xT29yLS42NvBVZVsA1Gm4xLC4z6pPBoxcuuUr0) to support the 4th try!

For the record, here's the [1st attempt by someone else](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101509/greek-language) and [my 2nd](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/117994/greek-language), [3rd](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/120649/greek-language?referrer=6xe40guy8MPh_bKhvH06tg2) attempt by me.

Comment: I encourage anyone interested in Greek to join and--more importantly--to vote for good questions with a score less than 10. Currently there are enough users interested in the proposal but not enough questions with a vote of 10 or more.

Comment: I reworded the question a little, since there have been more Greek proposals in the past. I also featured the question so that it is shown on our main page. The [Area 51 rules have recently changed](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27938/117372) and it's important to get question suggestions fast if the site is ever to take off. Asking and voting are crucial now.

Comment: When you launch a new iteration of a proposal, I suggest starting a new meta discussion instead of editing an old one. It can get more visibility that way, and it preserves the record of past events.

Comment: Please don't edit an old meta question for a new purpose. Ask a new question instead! That way it'll get more visibility, too, due to the way new questions are prioritized. I rolled this question back to its original form, but you can see your new question from the [edit history](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/226/revisions) if you want to copy and paste.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the poster cannot follow instructions about the proposal. Plus, it's spam.