# Would "Greek".SE affect the definition of this site?

Tags: discussion, scope, greek

This site is called "Latin", but also accepts questions about ancient Greek.

There is now a proposal [Greek - Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/128045/greek), for both ancient and modern Greek.

If it succeeds, will the definition of "on-topic" change for *this* site?

Comment: Related questions: [why are there questions about the greek language on here](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261/why-are-there-questions-about-the-greek-language-on-here?rq=1) and [how would the community feel about other classical languages](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-would-the-latin-se-community-feel-about-opening-the-site-up-to-further-class?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Also worth noting from the comments on the above that this is at least the third time that a Greek SE site has been on Area 51; maybe the third time's the charm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### No

No, the scope of this site wouldn't feel much of an effect.
It's perfectly fine for a question to be on topic on several SE sites, so there are no immediate and obvious consequences to our scope if a Greek site is launched.

[Our Greek policy](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/358/79) explicitly excludes modern Greek, whereas a wholly Greek site is likely to be largely about just that if all kinds of Greek is included.

#### Don't count on success

There have been several attempts to launch a Greek site, and [this meta question](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/226/79) lists three.
The first few questions in the current proposal aren't faring great, so I'm not convinced that it's going to take off.

I would like to see a Greek site succeed, but it will take more organized effort than what has been tried so far.
The important thing is to find an active community or a core group of it before going to Area 51.
If you start from scratch there, gaining enough traction quick enough is nigh impossible.
Just setting up a proposal at Area 51 and hoping for the best is not going to work.
With a hot new topic it just might, but with Greek experience shows that it won't.

#### Cross the bridge when we get there

If a Greek site is successfully launched and gets through the beta stage into SE adulthood, then it is here to stay.
Otherwise it is still on probation, and we shouldn't do anything too major before things have settled.
If a Greek site gets there, it will have defined its scope and found its community, and all the details involved will factor into our decision on including Greek here on the Latin site.
I find it premature to speculate; if you want to spend time planning, try to think instead of a concrete way to launch a Greek site successfully.

In my opinion SE sites are more about communities than topics.
(I mean communities as people interested in a topic, not just as the users that frequent a specific site.)
The community of scholars, learners, teachers, and enthusiasts of Latin overlaps greatly with that of ancient Greek.
The two languages aren't close enough to warrant inclusion of both on the same site but the two groups of people are.